# Finder method not returing latest record in EJB 2.1

Tags: entity

I am using EJB 2.1 and I am stuck with a problem.

There is one method in which I call a stored procedure which updates a particular record in DB (primary key is 'id') and once the procedure is executed, I am calling findByPrimaryKey(id) to get the same record.

Both the calls are in a single method.

Problem I am facing is I am getting the old record (not the updated one) using findByPrimaryKey(id). But I want the updated record.

I understand may be the transaction is not completed so finder is giving old record. But I need this to get it work. Please help.